# Jersey 2 + HK2 - @ApplicationScoped not working

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey-2.0, hk2

I have class

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Service{
 private Map<String, Integer> something ;
 private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Service.class);

 @PostConstruct
 public void initialize(){
    something = new HashMap<>();
 }

 public void increase(String userName){
    something.put(userName, something.getOrDefault(userName, 0) + 1);
 }

 public Map<String, Integer> getSomething(){
    return this.something;
 }

 public Integer getSomethingForUser(String userName){
    return something.getOrDefault(userName, 0);
 }
}
```

Which I want to be globally one instance.

The problem is, that when I'm injecting this service in two different places, I have two different instances of the service - which causes to return always counter `0`. `.toString()` returns as follows:

```
package.services.Service@492e4f4b
package.services.Service@4bc86c4d
```

I created this service to test my HK2-Jersey implementation, which is apparently not working as should.

Web.xml:

```
<servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>io.swagger.jaxrs.listing,mypackage.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>
            io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource,
            io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>mypackage.config.ApplicationConfiguration</param-value>
      </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

ApplicationConfiguration.java:

```
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {
public ApplicationConfiguration() {
     register(new AbstractBinder() {
         @Override
         protected void configure() {
             bind(Service.class).to(Service.class);    
         }
     });

    packages(true, "com.mypackage.rest");
}
```

}

Without this `bind` function, server throws exception that `@Inject` wasn't satisfied.

Can anybody point out, what is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such thing as `@ApplicationScoped` in HK2. That is only CDI (which is different). In HK2 there's a singleton scope. With your configuration, you can either do

```
bind(new Service()).to(Service.class);
```

which will automatically make it a singleton. Only problem with this is that you lose any injection by the container (if you require any). The other way is to set the scope in the `in(Scope)` method

```
bind(Service.class).to(Service.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

That's `javax.inject.Singleton`.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Can you maybe say, If there's any automatic way to bind those classess or I have to manually add them here?

Comment: If you want to post another question, I'd be glad to answer it.

Comment: I think that Jersey has its own definition of @ApplicationScoped.  The reason you might have been seeing different instances is because it is a proxied scope, and therefor the proxies injected are different even if the underlying actual services you would get are the same (use equals rather than == to compare)

Comment: @peeskillet, as you've requested, I've created new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37794144/jersey-2-hk2-automatic-binding-of-classess. Thank you very much for help.